# Webmatrix - How do you add data to an SQL database using a reusable function?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, function, webmatrix

As a learning exercise I'm trying to set up a webpage written in html and c# using an SQL database. I'm currently trying to add predefined data to a database, using a reusable function that can be called from anywhere. The data should be added when a button is clicked. In my App_Code folder I have a file named Functions.cshtml with the following:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Text;
@functions {

    public static void AddNewProduct(string ProductName, string Category, double Price, double PurchasePrice, int Stock)
    {  
    var db = Database.Open("Cafeen");  
    db.Execute("INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Category, Price, PurchasePrice, Stock) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)", ProductName, Category, Price, PurchasePrice, Stock); 
    Response.Redirect("~/Members/Products");
    }        
}
```

In another file called TestArea.cshtml I have the following:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.title = "TestArea";
}

@if(IsPost){
    Functions.AddNewProduct("Jolly", "Sodavand", 12.00, 8.00, 120);
}

    <p><input type="submit" name="TestSubmit" value="Add product" /></p>
```

Having only worked in F# previously, I have no idea how to get these different parts to work together, or if my implementation of AddNewProduct is correct. Any advice? I hope I haven't asked a stupid question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks reasonable.  The only thing i'm not sure about is the function file and the @function notation.  We used this a long time ago, but stopped because it didn't gracefully work in a full blown visual studio/web pages environment.   Does yours work or give error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I'm not receiving any error messages, but it doesn't work either. When clicking the button, nothing happens. If there's a smarter way than using @functions, then I'm open to it. What do you suggest? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be that there's not a form.  Make the TestArea.cshtml look more like:

```
@if(IsPost)
{
    <h1>Yes, it Posted<h1>
    // Functions.AddNew......  like you had it
}

<form method="post">
  something: <input type="text" name="enter name"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="TestSubmit" value="Add product" />
</form>
```

I've added a form, and temporarily commented out your function.  First make sure the post works then get the function working.  If the post does work, they way i've written it above, you'll see the Yes, it works! show up in your page.

As to the functions, we create a pure .cs file in app_code that just has c# code in it.  It means you have to create classes instead of functions, but probably closer to F# that way anyway.

Comment: I assume that `<h1>Yes, it Posted<h1>` should be `<h1>Yes, it Posted</h1>` ? 
The page loads up all right, with the input field and the button showing, but still nothing happens when clicking the button. My editor give a warning relating to `<method="post">` saying "Unknown element 'method' or element cannot be placed here. Not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Changed `<method="post">` to `<form action="TestArea.cshtml" method="post">` and now it works. Going test my old code now. Thanks for everything so far!
EDIT: Works like a charm :)

Comment: yes, glad you fixed my bug.   I edited it to be correct.  Mark the answer correct please.